# GeoServer: This connection is not secure. Logins entered here could be compromised

Tags: geoserver, ssl

I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-on-ubuntu-22-04) article on a Debian machine and then added SSL with Certbot (my padlock is fine). The message comes up when I click the user/password input box. It seems like a mixed content warning but I don't know what Nginx or GeoServer configuration I need to change. I have v2.22.2.

Comment: Do you access the geoserver via https:// ? Also, is that a browser error message or where does it originate? Maybe a screenshot would clarify that.
Also: do you try to access the ngix reverse proxy or do you access the geoserver?

Comment: @til_b yes and it's a browser message. It's [this (different site, same message)](https://www.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/this-connection-is-not-secure.jpg).

Comment: @til_b I'm not sure what gets accessed by default but I do have Nginx running. I do get a Powered by Eclipse Jetty:// Server message when I open my main domain so maybe it's skipping Nginx.

Comment: @til_b when I stop Nginx, the page doesn't load at all, so I think it is being used.

Comment: I guess then it's not a problem specific to geoserver and GIS.SE is not the place to ask. Maybe ask at superuser.com ?

Answer (score 2):

Please set up your "proxy base URL" so that it uses the https address:

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#proxy-base-url

Comment: What do I do after adding -DALLOW_ENV_PARAMETRIZATION=true to geoserver-environment.properties in data_dir?

Comment: To be honest I don't remember if you can env parameterize the proxy base... what is normally done, is to provide http headers from the proxy itself, which are used by GeoServer in a proxy base template. See the link above again, it describes how templates are used, too.